# Rails Sanitizer Loofah gem removes text after `<`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nokogiri

So I'm currently using loofah to sanitize my html. So I'm using an older version of rails/ruby so I can't upgrade my loofah and nokogiri and etc. Basically, any text after `<` will be erased. For example, `Hello <Testing` will become `Hello`. I want to be able to do things like `Is 1 < 3?` without it removing the 3. I tested it with newer version and it worked so I'm wondering if there is a workaround this issue and still working with the older versions of loofah/nokogiri?

Currently using these versions

- loofah 1.0.0
- nokogiri 1.5.9
- libxml 2.9.4
- Rails 2.3.18
- Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Maybe there _is_ a workaround, who knows. If only you posted actual versions and some kind of a [mcve], then this question would have a chance to be answerable.

Comment: Sorry on my part. I added the versions. :(